# WPF calling WCF with Windows Authentication - Not working

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, .net-4.0

I am developing a WPF application in .NET 4.0 which calls a WCF Service hosted on the server developed in .NET 4.0.

I want to use windows authentication for this purpose and it seems that it is not working and keep on giving me following error.

> The provided URI scheme 'http' is
>   invalid; expected 'https'. Parameter
>   name: via

I do not want to use https as this is an Intranet application. The WCF Service in turn calls SQL Server SPs via Entity Framework 4.0.

It works fine locally but as soon as I put that on server and it stops working. I can access the service via Browser and I can reference it as well but as soon as I access one of the method and I get above error. Any idea? Is it possible to call WCF Service without https?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

TheITGuy

PS: I want to list my `web.config` and `app.config` but for some reason its not working. Wonder why?

Comment: "some reason its not working" : What is not working? This site?

Comment: If you want to post code or XML (config), you need to highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its working now by setting the Security mode to TransportWithCredentialOnly.

Thanks for everyone's reply.